# How to get the native heap size and the dalvik heap size of my app

Tags: android, memory-management, android-memory

From my app, How to get the **native heap size** and the **Dalvik heap size** ?

Comment: Check dumpsys meminfo <app>

Comment: @iVoid: I need to do it from inside my app

Comment: Use `ActivityManager#getProcessMemoryInfo(int[])` and then `Debug.MemoryInfo#getSummaryNativeHeap()` and `Debug.MemoryInfo#getSummaryJavaHeap()`. Or parse the `/proc/<PID>/smaps` file directly.